# Intersection Error with Multiple VBA Loops

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a code to move rows into separate sheets based on input, I have it working for one case as shown below:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim C As Range
If Intersect(Target, me.Range("AN:AN")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
For Each C In Intersect(Target, me.Range("AN:AN")).Cells
   If C.Text "Y" Then
     C.EntireRow.Copy Worksheets("Closed").Cells(Rows.Couint, "AN").End(xlUp).Offset(1).EntireRow
     C.EntireRow.Delete
   End If
   Next
End Sub
```

Now I want to have a seperate case for a seperate column reference but when I try and repeat the code into the same subroutine I get an error '1004 intersect error', I have tried quite a few things but the error seems to always be thrown with the second intersect statement:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim C, B As Range
If Intersect(Target, me.Range("AN:AN")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
For Each C In Intersect(Target, me.Range("AN:AN")).Cells
   If C.Text "Y" Then
     C.EntireRow.Copy Worksheets("Closed").Cells(Rows.Count, "AN").End(xlUp).Offset(1).EntireRow
     C.EntireRow.Delete
   End If
   Next
If Intersect(Target, me.Range("D:D")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
For Each B In Intersect(Target, me.Range("D:D")).Cells
   If B.Text "Q" Then
     B.EntireRow.Copy Worksheets("Quoted").Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Offset(1).EntireRow
     B.EntireRow.Delete
   End If
   Next
End Sub
```

I tried to group the two presence checks into one statement at the start but it still threw an error during the second loop, as shown:

```
    If Intersect(Target, me.Range("AN:AN, D:D")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
```

Comment: You are missing a number of = Combining won't work if intersect is only in one range

Comment: Won't work as written ^^. I would also go with If Not Intersect(Target, Range("AN:AN, D:D")) Is Nothing Then..... and determine action based on target.column  (Also restrict to smaller range where possible)

Comment: I had to transfer it by hand so I missed out on some =, so essentially I need to change the intersect statement to target.column and get rid of the range for both iterations, having the range only be used to check presence?

Comment: At this point `If Intersect(Target, me.Range("AN:AN")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub` your procedure exits if Target isn't in column AN. Then, how could this line `If Intersect(Target, me.Range("D:D")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub` ever be reached?

Comment: Does your second (D) intersect run OK by itself?

Answer (score 0):

My intention is to show you an approach, not to give you a working solution. Here is the approach.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Dim Rng         As Range            ' Action range
    Dim Cell        As Range            ' loop
    Dim Crit        As String           ' selection criterium
    Dim Ws          As Worksheet        ' Worksheet to copy to
    Dim C           As Long             ' Target column
    
    ' Columns("D") = Columns(4), "AN" = Columns("AN").Column [=40]
    Set Rng = Intersect(Target, Application.Union(Columns("D"), Columns("AN")))
    If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
        C = Target.Column
        Crit = IIf(C = 4, "Quoted", "Closed")       ' Columns("D") = Columns(4)
        Set Ws = Worksheets(Crit)
        Crit = IIf(C = 4, "Q", "Y")
        
        For Each Cell In Rng.Cells
            With Ws
                If Cell.Value = Crit Then
                    Cell.EntireRow.Copy .Cells(.Rows.Count, C).End(xlUp).Offset(1).EntireRow
                    Cell.EntireRow.Delete
                End If
            End With
        Next Cell
    End If
End Sub
```

And here is what's wrong with the code.

1. Your loop looks at each cell in the range at the intersection of your columns and the change area. Most of the time the change will occur in only one cell, and that's fine. But if you paste a number of cells then `Target` comprises all the intersecting cells. Say, you paste to an area A3:F20, the intersecting area will be D3:D20 and each of those cells will be processed. That's fine, too - if you are aware of it.
2. The `For .. Each` loop will process the cells in the sequence they inherit from their location on the sheet. In my above example, D3 will be processed first. When row 3 is deleted the rows below it move up. All the following deletions will therefore occur in the wrong row. Therefore you can't use `For .. Each` in that case. Instead you must start at the last cell, moving up to the first, and changes in row numbers will occur only below the new deletion where they don't matter. So, you should use `For R = [Last row in Rng] to [First row in Rng] Step -1`
3. `.Cells(.Rows.Count, C)` Observe the leading periods before "Cells" and "Rows". The rows count must be taken in the same worksheet where the Cells range is located. But why do you determine the **next** row in column C (meaning D or AN)? The answer is because all columns have the same length. But logically, that should cause you to measure the length in column A. Which brings me to my last point.
4. I have never seen this construct before: `Cell.EntireRow.Copy .Cells(.Rows.Count, C).End(xlUp).Offset(1).EntireRow`. I presume that it actually works (I didn't test) but the Destination would normally be a single cell. The single and correct cell emerging logically from your code is in column A. So, why do you go to some length to find the last cell in either column D or AN whereas all the while you really need the cell in column A? `Cell.EntireRow.Copy .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)` should serve you equally well.

Comment: I don't code at all in VBA, but I have spent a while trying to decipher your solution and it looks like it should work already? But if not I am going to use it to make it work tomorrow on the spreadsheet. Thank you.

Comment: oh, now I understand. Your comments are about your own code. So It would process D3 because it is offset by 1? And row 1 is full of headers?